# Continuity of function does not imply continuity of extension

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be increasing on a dense subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}$, and define $\tilde{f}$ on $x\in\mathbb{R}$ $\tilde{f}(x):=\inf_{x<t\in D}f(t)$. Show that the continuity of $f$ on $D$ does not imply that of $\tilde{f}$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

I have tried rational/irrational number(s) with characteristic function(s), but doesn't seem to work. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you know what kind of discontinuities a monotonic function can have?

Comment: Yes I do, jump discontinuity.

Comment: Good. So where could $\tilde{f}$ jump so that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Well I thought a countable set and obvious candidate was $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Maybe simpler if you take e.g. $D = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Very neat. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $D=\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $1$ if $x>0$. Then $\overline{f}(0)=1$.